# Action upon leaving a web page with Django

Tags: django

This is a general question with no attempt so far since I don't know where to start.  All I've seen are javascript alerts upon leaving a page.

**Scenario:**

- When **User1** visit a page I want to generate a random string and make an entry in the database for that string.
- This random number can be entered by **one** other user (**User2**).
- I will check that the random number has an entry in the database before allowing **User2** to "proceed"

When **User1** leaves the page, I want to remove the entry from the database, so that if **User2** enters the random string, it won't be present in the database any longer/ won't be valid anymore.

**How do I trigger an event to delete the row upon leaving the page?**

Not sure how else to describe this -- if I'm making this more difficult than it needs to be or I'm just approaching the problem wrong, please point me in the right direction as to how to pull this off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps someone can prove me wrong, but as far as I know there isn't a reliable way of triggering a server-side event when users leave a page.

Yes, there is the `onunload` event that you can use to trigger a quick ajax call, but HTTP is by definition a stateless protocol and attempting to create a solution which emulate a stateful *connection* will have flaws.  Consider:

- users terminating the browser process instead of simply leaving the page
- browsers with javascript disabled

From your scenario, I suspect that you might be approaching your problem from a wrong angle. Do give more details on what you're trying to achieve and someone might be able to help.